Remove auto modifier from compose function in Jellyfish
After updating Android Studio to Jellyfish, when I try to create a compose function using the "comp" keyword, the modifier is automatically added as a parameter to the function, how do I disable this?



This may seem annoying, but it's actually best practice (no direct link possible, scroll up one parapgrah) to have a default Modifier parameter for your compose functions that is then applied to the outer most composable in that function. This new behavior of Android Studio actually encourages good practice and should therefore, in most cases, not be changed.

I agree, but now in at least half of the cases it’s just a boilerplate

In AS Jellyfish this was added as default behavior. To change it, move to Settings/Editor/Live templates, then find a comp template. You'll see something like this
@androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
fun $NAME$(modifier: androidx.compose.ui.Modifier = androidx.compose.ui.Modifier) {
$END$
}

Now change it to
@androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
fun $NAME$() {
$END$
}

To restore default settings, click on template again with right mouse button then choise restore defaults as on screen below.
Do not forget apply changes.

